# eb: error: unrecognized arguments: --database.engine.version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

According to the AWS EB documentation for [`eb create`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html), I should be able to create an elastic beanstalk environment with an postgres database, via this command:

```
eb create myapp-env --database.engine.version postgres-9.4.1                                                                                        
usage: eb {cmd} <environment_name> [options ...]
eb: error: unrecognized arguments: --database.engine.version postgres-9.4.1
```

I've also tried these command line arguments to no avail:

```
 eb create myapp-env -db.engine postgres --database.engine.version 9.4.1
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation references the wrong parameter, use this command instead:

`eb create myapp-env -db.engine postgres --database.version 9.4.1`

Further info about this here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=607852#607852

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure you have eb cli 3 installed.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html

It is slightly different from the eb cli 2.6 version.

Comment: `eb --version
#=> EB CLI 3.2 (Python 2.7.6)`